# How to pass main report field to subreport query

Tags: mysql, join, jasper-reports

How to pass main report field to subreport query.
Main report Query:

```
select pd.ID_DIMENSION as IDDIM,
    pd.NOMBRE as pdnombre,
    pdi.VALOR_PONDERACION_GOB as pdipond,
    pdi.VALOR_PONDERADO as pdiponderado 
from pgs_indice pi 
    join pgh_indice_vigencia piv on piv.ID_INDICE = pi.ID_INDICE 
    JOIN pgh_dimension_indice pdi ON piv.ID_INDICE_VIGENCIA = pdi.ID_INDICE_VIGENCIA 
    JOIN pgb_dimension pd ON pd.ID_DIMENSION = pdi.ID_DIMENSION 
where pi.ID_INDICE = $P{INDICE} AND piv.VIGENCIA = $P{VIGENCIA}
```

Sub-report Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pc.NOMBRE as pcnombre,
    pcd.VALOR_PONDERACION_GOB as pcdpond,
    pcd.VALOR_PONDERACION as pcdponderacion,
    FORMAT(((pcd.VALOR_PONDERACION_GOB * 100) / (pcd.VALOR_PONDERACION_GOB + pcd.VALOR_PONDERACION)),2) as pcdpondgobcal,
    FORMAT(((pcd.VALOR_PONDERACION * 100) / (pcd.VALOR_PONDERACION_GOB + pcd.VALOR_PONDERACION)),2) as pcdpondcal
FROM pgs_indice indi 
    JOIN pgh_indice_vigencia piv ON piv.ID_INDICE = indi.ID_INDICE 
    JOIN pgh_dimension_indice pdi ON piv.ID_INDICE_VIGENCIA = pdi.ID_INDICE_VIGENCIA 
    JOIN pgb_dimension pd ON pd.ID_DIMENSION =pdi.ID_DIMENSION 
    JOIN pgh_categoria_dimension pcd ON pcd.ID_DIMENSION_INDICE = pdi.ID_DIMENSION_INDICE 
    JOIN pgb_categoria pc ON pc.ID_CATEGORIA = pcd.ID_CATEGORIA 
    JOIN pgh_indicador_categoria pic ON pic.ID_CATEGORIA_DIMENSION = pcd.ID_CATEGORIA_DIMENSION 
    JOIN pgb_indicador pi ON pi.ID_INDICADOR = pic.ID_INDICADOR 
WHERE indi.ID_INDICE = $P{INDICE} 
    AND piv.VIGENCIA =  $P{VIGENCIA}  
    AND pd.ID_DIMENSION =1 Here
```

I want Use Main report Field ('pd.ID_DIMENSION as IDDIM,') in subreport query in where condition:

```
(WHERE indi.ID_INDICE = $P{INDICE} AND piv.VIGENCIA =  $P{VIGENCIA}  AND pd.ID_DIMENSION = Here I want use)
```

Answer (score 0):

U need to pass parameter pd.ID_DIMENSION to sub report.

1. in your main report, click at the subreport, at the properties, click at Parameters.
2. it will bring Parameters box. Click Add, enter parameter name eg: `ID_DIMENSION`.
3. for Value Expression, select the field you want to pass to subreport eg: `$F{ID_DIMENSION}`
4. in your sub report, Add new Paramater, and name it same just what u pass from main report, `ID_DIMENSION`
5. alter your sub report query to use paramater from main report. `... AND pd.ID_DIMENSION = $P{ID_DIMENSION}`

Good luck.

Comment: i have another questions.
are you there?